# Metallparts on package design

Tags: texturing, uv

[image]I'm doing a pretty simple packaging design. A rectangular box with the graphics on.

My problem comes in parts that have metal foil punched into the design itself. Text and a some sort of swosch.

How do I get those parts metallic without affecting the paper parts with image texture?

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Could you please add some images to illustrate your question?

Comment: Hi and thanks! I'm new at 3D so it might be an easy thing to do. but I haven't found a good solution yet

Answer (score 0):

You have already got your image map and UV done? Then all you need to add is the bump, roughness map for the emboss. For the metal look you will need a metallic map for the metal text. If you don't know what a metallic map is then you will have to do a quick search on shading for blender.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!